# Newline in sub-replace expression

Tags: regular-expression

I've been trying to write a regex that turns the following structure

```
# Ignore this line

Foo
Foo

# Ignore this line too
```

into:

```
# Ignore this line

IF BAR THEN
    Foo
    Foo

# Ignore this line too
```

So far I have the following regex:

```
%s#\(\n\)\?\(\(Foo\n\)\+\)\(\n\)\?#\= submatch(1) . 'IF BAR THEN\r' . 
substitute(submatch(2), 'Foo', '    &', 'g') . submatch(4)#gc
```

Which gives me:

```
# Ignore this line

IF BAR THEN\r    FOO
    Foo

# Ignore this line
```

I have tried using `\n`, `<CR>`, `^M` but none seem to have the desired output. Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a literal string (delimited by single quotes) where you want to use an escape character `\r`.

Replace them with double quotes to fix:

```
... "IF BAR THEN\r" ...
```

(See `:help string`.)